# How to get count all json nodes using Jackson framework

Tags: java, web-services, jackson

Here is my user.json

```
{  
    "id":1,
    "name":{  
        "first":"Yong",
        "last":"Mook Kim"
    },
    "contact":[  
        {  
            "type":"phone/home",
            "ref":"111-111-1234"
        },
        {  
            "type":"phone/work",
            "ref":"222-222-2222"
        }
    ]
},
{  
    "id":2,
    "name":{  
        "first":"minu",
        "last":"Zi Lap"
    },
    "contact":[  
        {  
            "type":"phone/home",
            "ref":"333-333-1234"
        },
        {  
            "type":"phone/work",
            "ref":"444-444-4444"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like count how many json object is in there. For example the above json has 2 json object id = 1 and id =2.

```
//tree model approach
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();    
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(new File("user.json"));    
List<JsonNode> listOfNodes = rootNode.findParents("first");
System.out.println(listOfNodes.size());
```

Giving me size = 1.

Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I see 8 `{` / `}` pairs, so that means 8 JSON objects. And 2 JSON arrays.. Also, that is not valid JSON, as there are two objects separated by comma, so you need a `[` / `]` pair around the entire thing, making it 3 JSON arrays.

Comment: Let me put it this way. I want the "first" value which id = 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your java code is correct but your json file is invalid. 
Jackson parses only first valid element ("Yong").

To fix this just add `[` at the begining and `]` at the end of file (make it array).

Comment: Thanks Maciej. Sometimes small thing get ignored. I added [ at the beginning and at the end and it fixed now.