# Getting counts of arrays in a JsonNode

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json structure like this:

```
{
  "MetricDataResults": [
    {
      "Id": "m1",
      "StatusCode": "Complete",
      "Label": "AWS/EC2 NetworkOut Average",
      "Timestamps": [
        1518868032,
        1518867732,
        1518867432
      ],
      "Values": [
        15000,
        14000,
        16000
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": "m2",
      "StatusCode": "Complete",
      "Label": "AWS/EC2 NetworkOut SampleCount",
      "Timestamps": [
        1518868032,
        1518867732,
        1518867432
      ],
      "Values": [
        15,
        14,
        16
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": "m3",
      "StatusCode": "Complete",
      "Label": "AWS/EC2 HealthyHostCount",
      "Timestamps": [
        1518868032,
        1518867732,
        1518867432
      ],
      "Values": [
        15,
        14,
        16
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For this json structure I need the counts of arrays in it. I'm looking at the structure to look like something like this:

```
{
  "MetricDataResults (3)": [
    {
      "Id": "m1",
      "StatusCode": "Complete",
      "Label": "AWS/EC2 NetworkOut Average",
      "Timestamps (3)": [
        1518868032,
        1518867732,
        1518867432
      ],
      "Values (3)": [
        15000,
        14000,
        16000
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": "m2",
      "StatusCode": "Complete",
      "Label": "AWS/EC2 NetworkOut SampleCount",
      "Timestamps (3)": [
        1518868032,
        1518867732,
        1518867432
      ],
      "Values (3)": [
        15,
        14,
        16
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": "m3",
      "StatusCode": "Complete",
      "Label": "AWS/EC2 HealthyHostCount",
      "Timestamps (4)": [
        1518868032,
        1518867732,
        1518867432,
        1518867462,
      ],
      "Values (4)": [
        15,
        14,
        16,
        18
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a particular way with which we get the counts when deserializing with jackson? I was looking at this post - [How to get count all json nodes using Jackson framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056203/how-to-get-count-all-json-nodes-using-jackson-framework)

but that doesn't seem to completely align with the use case I have. Does anybody have an idea on whether this can be done?

Comment: Do you want to rename each field whose value is an array so the field name includes the number of elements in the array?

Comment: Yeah, that's something I could work with. The problem is that I don't want the number of elements for a particular array, but all the nodes which represent an array

Comment: You could took at https://github.com/anatolygudkov/green-jelly. Parse your JSON and increment a counter in onArrayStarted() callback. Also, both Jackson and Gson support streaming parsing. Use such event-based technique to count "array started" tokens